# Jmeter failed to run JUnit Test jar

Tags: eclipse, junit, jmeter, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am trying to **execute** a **Jar** in **JMeter** to **load-test my Orientdb application**.

**Some details about my application :**

- My application print(sysout) some logs on console on startup like

  `System is starting, loading data...

  data loaded successfully from file..!

  connecting to server to save data..`
- Then it connect to Orientdb server to save data there

I **run** my **JUnit test** case using **eclipse**, its **running successfully** like

- printing logs on console (sysouts)
- connecting to Orientdb server and **writing data** there **successfully**

**Problem :**

**When I am trying to run this JUnit test case by building jar using JMeter** :

- **JMeter** **print** my startup **logs** to **console**(which means jar is executing) like :

  System is starting, loading data...

  data loaded successfully from file..!

  connecting to server to save data..
- **But**  **after that JMeter exit and give this error**

  `An unexpected error occured
  Error -- executeGraph(org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$AnnotatedTestCase): com/orientechnologies/orient/client/remote/OServerAdmin`
- At this point when its giving error, **ideally it should connect to orientdb and write data their.**

**Note** : I am **executing** JMeter using **jmeter.bat** and **JUnit** **version**  is **v4.11**

Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to put any dependency jars your application uses somewhere on [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (copy them to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation). In the majority of cases JMeter restart will be required to pick the libraries up. If after that your JUnit test case will still be failing - check *jmeter.log* file - it normally contains all the troubleshooting information.

---

You can also consider using [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler for creating the load onto your OrientDB instance. You will still need the relevant [JDBC driver](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb-jdbc.wiki/Home.html) in classpath, however you won't need any other jars, see [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article for configuration details.